# Bootstrap dropdown in navbar has unwanted space

Tags: css

I have a bootstrap navbar with a dropdown as shown below. There is an undesired whitespace appearing as highlighted in the image. How can this be fixed? Also, what is the best bootstrap way to adjust height and appearance of each list item in the dropdown?

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/q567pn6b/1/

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ui-widget-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px;">
                    <span>
                        <!--<img src="../../Images/test-48.ico" height="48" alt="">-->
                    </span>
                    <div id="divBrandNameText" class="cookieFontGoogle" style="display:inline-block;color:#FFFFFF; vertical-align:central;">Brand</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">


                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="padding-right:3px;"></i>HOME</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="padding-right:3px;"></span>ADMIN<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Deactivate</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" style="padding-right:3px;"></i>ABOUT US</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


                <form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post">
                    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="kr1aZLmir-Xd707LG45t6gYyoT6p31yghXGfqmNZDdLGbvnS6ra6jWQWbzVNxrH7P3CIo7tk71MjLuHSKEV8U1zXQQ48y5nBBt2297Hf5OPRo5RMl9FRFq_nZImd9lnLXiZW5XXLE1EyAwC72VMKhA2" />        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/" title="Manage">Hello Admin!</a>
                        </li>


                        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content" style="padding-top:25px;">

        Test

    </div>
```

**JS**

```
// Add slideDown animation to Bootstrap dropdown when expanding.
        $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
        });

        // Add slideUp animation to Bootstrap dropdown when collapsing.
        $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
        });
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
            background-color: #00A0F0;
        }

        .navbar-fixed-top {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #0078A0;
        }

        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

            .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
            .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
                color: #737373;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color: #00A0F1;
        }

            .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
            .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #00A0F1;
        }

        .cookieFontGoogle {
            font: 200 50px/1.3 'Cookie', Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got some padding on your class .dropdown-menu, override it with:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following css. the bigFontNavbar is defined to increase navbar height as you are using a big font for Brand text.

```
.bigFontNavbar {min-height: 65px;}
.bigFontNavbar .navbar-toggle {margin-top: 15px;}
.bigFontNavbar .navbar-collapse {padding-top: 8px;}

.dropdown-menu { background-color: #00A0F1 !important; border:none; }

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {background: none !important;}

.ui-widget-header { background-size: cover; }

.dropdown-menu > li > a { padding: 5px 10px; }
```

[as in this updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q567pn6b/3/)

please give feedback if you want to do something else about the appearance of menu items.